# Calculating Error for Taylor Series (Calculus II)

Tags: convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

Problem:

Estimate the error if $P_3(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{6}$ is used to estimate the value of $\sin(x)$ at $x = 0.5$

Can someone explain how I'm getting this wrong? I'm using the formula (M|x-a|^(n+1))/(n+1)!.

So far, what I understand are my variables are a=0, $M = 1, n = 3$, and $x = 0.5$. (Or at least I think so)

When I plug those in I get $0.0026042$, rounded to the $7$ decimals place. Any info about where I went wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you obtain the error estimate $$\frac{M |x - 1|^{n + 1}}{n + 1}$$?

Comment: Just edited the question, thanks!

Comment: The number you get after plugging in $a, M, n, x$ should also change, right?